# VB.NET: Build project, then share application: OK?

Tags: vb.net, build, path

In VB.NET, my application is quite simple, and it accesses many images and creates a list with them.

The images are in my application's Resources folder.
The images are accessed in my code where I typed the path, in my PC, how to reach said folder.

Works like a charm, my project displays the images etc.

Now I go to Debug->Build.

Now I go to the bin folder, release folder, and find my application. I upload it.
I share the download to a friend.

My question is, will the images my application should show will appear? Considering the path I created in the code was manually written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the images compiled into your project as "Embedded Resources" or placed in a .resx file? Is the code that you've written accessing them from your project's Resources folder? If so, then everything will work just fine when you copy the application to another computer and run it.

If you're hard-coding a path to your file system, then no; your application won't work on another computer because those files won't be distributed along with the bare executable. There's really no reason to ever do this.

It's difficult to tell from the information provided in your question what exactly you're doing. For more information about embedding resources into your application itself, so all you have to do is distribute the executable, see this simple how-to guide: [Using Resources in Visual Studio .NET](http://www.jelovic.com/articles/resources_in_visual_studio.htm)

Comment: "Adding a new RESX file to a project is simple. Simply right-click on a project in the Solution Explorer, select Add/Add New Resource, and add a new "Assembly Resource File"........... I can't do that. There is no "Assembly Resource File"

Comment: @Omega: Just use Add -> Add New Item. A dialog box will appear. Scroll down to "Resources File", name it, and click "Add". (I guess the article refers to an older version of Visual Studio and this has been changed. Not sure why.)